# Show agreement or similarity with "so could it be" or "so could it"?

Tags: sentence

I have this sentence:

> As this problematic situation could be applied to Europe, so could
>   the way of dealing with it *be*

I don't know whether the last *be* should be removed or not. Is it correct as it is written now?

When writing *so do I* or similar structures (*so could I*,...), can it be followed by a sentence or does it have to stop with those three words?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the one without *be*.

> "*As this problematic situation could be applied to Europe, so could the way of dealing with it*."

the *be* alternative sounds inelegant and awkward to my ear.

Answer (score 0):

Both statements (with and without *be*) are correct.

Your example sentences (with and without *be*) both use differing extents of *[verb phrase ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase_ellipsis)*, a linguistic phenomenon that occurs when a verb phrase (or part of a verb phrase) is "left out", or *elided*. The difference between the two sentences is that one has more of the verb phrase "left out" (the one without *be*). Verb phrase ellipsis varies; in fact, the following phrase would also be correct in the UK:

> As this problematic situation could be applied to Europe, so could the way of dealing with it be done.

Although [this article](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2007/09/pro-predicate-do-and-verb-phrase.html) mainly discusses the differences between verb phrase ellipsis in British and American English, it explains this linguistic concept in simpler terms.